# How to pick or access Indexer/Index signature property in a existing type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Edit: Changed title to reflect the problem properly.

I am trying to pick the exact type definition of a specific property inside a interface, but the property is a mapped type `[key: string]:` . I tried accessing it using `T[keyof T]` because it is the only property inside that type but it returns `never` type instead.

is there a way to like `Pick<Interface, [key: string]>` or `Interface[[key: string]]` to extract the type?

The interface I am trying to access is `type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';`

```js
export interface AWS {
  configValidationMode?: "error" | "warn" | "off";
  deprecationNotificationMode?: "error" | "warn" | "warn:summary";
  disabledDeprecations?: "*" | ErrorCode[];
  frameworkVersion?: string;
  functions?: {
    [k: string]: { // <--- Trying to pick this property.
      name?: string;
      events?: (
        | {
            __schemaWorkaround__: null;
          }
        | {
            schedule:
              | string
              | {
                  rate: string[];
                  enabled?: boolean;
                  name?: string;
                  description?: string;
                  input?:
                    | string

/// Didn't include all too long..
```

Comment: That's not a specific property of the type. It's an indexer.

Comment: Note that `{[k: string}: XXX}` is not a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html); it is a type with an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)... they are similar-looking syntaxes but they're not the same.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m358yw) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code to show a failed use case.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! it worked on my side. It's my first time hearing about index signatures, I should read the documentation more.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) here.  If you have an object-like type `T` and a key-like type `K` which is a valid key type for `T`, then `T[K]` is the type of the value at that key.  In other words, if you have a value `t` of type `T` and a value `k` of type `K`, then `t[k]` has the type `T[K]`.

So the first step here is to get the type of the `functions` property from the `AWS` type:

```
type Funcs = AWS["functions"];
/* type Funcs = {
    [k: string]: {
        name?: string | undefined;
        events?: {
            __schemaWorkaround__: null;
        } | {
            schedule: string | {
                rate: string[];
                enabled?: boolean;
                name?: string;
                description?: string;
                input?: string;
            };
        } | undefined;
    };
} | undefined */
```

Here `AWS` corresponds to the `T` in `T[K]`, and the `string` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"functions"` corresponds to the `K` type.

Because `functions` is an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of `AWS`, the `Funcs` type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the declared type of that property with `undefined`.  That's because if you have a value `aws` of type `AWS`, then `aws.functions` might be `undefined`.  You can't index into a possibly `undefined` value safely, so the compiler won't let you use an indexed access to type to drill down into `Funcs` directly.  Something like `Funcs[string]` will be an error.

---

So first we need to remove filter out the `undefined` type from `Functions`.  The easiest way to do this is with [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) which filters out `null` and `undefined` from a union type `T`:

```
type DefinedFuncs = NonNullable<Funcs>;
/* type DefinedFuncs = {
    [k: string]: {
        name?: string | undefined;
        events?: {
            __schemaWorkaround__: null;
        } | {
            schedule: string | {
                rate: string[];
                enabled?: boolean;
                name?: string;
                description?: string;
                input?: string;
            };
        } | undefined;
    };
} */
```

Okay, now we have a defined type with a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) whose property type is the type we're looking for.  Since any `string`-valued key can be used to get the property we're looking for, we can use an indexed access type with `DefinedFuncs` as the object type and `string` as the key type:

```
type DesiredProp = DefinedFuncs[string];
/* type DesiredProp = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    events?: {
        __schemaWorkaround__: null;
    } | {
        schedule: string | {
            rate: string[];
            enabled?: boolean;
            name?: string;
            description?: string;
            input?: string;
        };
    } | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good!  And of course we can do this all as a one-liner:

```
type DesiredProp = NonNullable<AWS["functions"]>[string];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQHUBlOAbwFgAoOObCJdBAcwDVMAbBAE0xgQYBZCN2AB+AFxwARGijRpcAD4yA7pihJFK6RHTppAbmq1RYKMGx8BSAHIR+TK-yEjxU2VHlRtajVuU-TQkAZwBXAFsIjQBPIxM4bgQQzAAjDmBuABFgc0trBhDJGQAqX0wkGIBtAF1jGjh0KEwI4FVoAGtWNBCbYpCYKGRmetp0MKRsFyQiqUoG2iqOqQGhpGYaubgAem24AB4AWmO4ABUoGOG4GAg4MARsDuuAC2S7+TA0GBiAOgTaWhIFruOCrYajAG0YAAN2AKFmcAAFP9IYF5qjUQB9TEhbDPYDRQidDQQCbcbFSJBhDgcCEYgC+KMhKnRGIBuPx3GpwAkTNRKjB6z5zPIwtRzVQK0Gw1qdLZUKB6UyxVSEAgGQqcvlQNa-Wl6y1bNEuKGYGmerWIzFkOQYDCMEk1oBAv1zCdjIWqI9GIAlCjvXAPR7qN9PnAAGITbAhOAAXgIJCq0nGk2mIWkdWo2xK1xiYcjkxj8dZi2WoNdm1FnshOpBguYgTJwCYSEyhqhsPhxRL8rg2I5BMwRKgHRJZIpcCpNPbgbRTtoA65GSllrn1d7tAlPPLltl89RcLSGW4KrVGqQM+1wIt4P3kON2FN5pXt-XG9t9pvBv39Jn9MbSCiC2bb+vU-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)